# Python - Appending Values

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I am reading data from a JSON file and i'm trying to append three calcs overall saydo, committed saydo and extra saydo based on a key (director + sprintname). I am getting the error below.
TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Code:

```
import json


with open('C:/Users/erpsaam/Desktop/report-v89/kpi-report-aggregation-by- 
director-2018-08-31.json') as f:
category_director_json = json.load(f)


category_director_dataset = []  # we will fill this in this script
for row in category_director_json:
row.get('director',None)
row.get('sprintName', None)
row.get('overallSayDo', None)
row.get('commitedSayDo', None)
row.get('extraSayDo', None)
category_director_dataset.append("DIRECTOR+SPRINTNAME", {'overallSayDo': 'overallSayDo_value', 'commitedSayDo': 'commitedSayDo_value', 'extraSayDo': 'extraSayDo_value'})
print(json.dumps(category_director_dataset))
```

Sample Data (JSON File)

```
[
{
    "teamName":"EPAM Backend 1,Cloud Engineering,Content Infrastructure Montreal,Jedi,Seal Team India - APIs,Seal Team India - Security,Seal Team X,Seal Team X India,Sith,UC Live,WeRTV,Krazy Kanucks,Seal Team India - Core,Operator Portal",
    "sprintName":"MF-S98",
    "director":"Rajesh",
    "locations":"Ukraine,SC,Duluth,India,Montreal,LA",
    "countries":"U.S.,Ukraine,Canada,Serbia,Spain,India",
    "cities":"Santa Clara,Ontario Quebec,Duluth,Bangalore,L.A.",
    "vendors":"EPAM,FTE,ITC,L&T TS,G&L,Phalita,Assistera",
    "overallSayDo":17.43,
    "commitedSayDo":9.86,
    "extraSayDo":18.14
},
{
    "teamName":"EPAM Backend 1,Cloud Engineering,Content Infrastructure Montreal,Jedi,Seal Team India - APIs,Seal Team India - Security,Seal Team X,Seal Team X India,Sith,UC Live,WeRTV,Krazy Kanucks,Seal Team India - Core,Operator Portal",
    "sprintName":"MF-S97",
    "director":"Rajesh",
    "locations":"Ukraine,SC,Duluth,India,Montreal,LA",
    "countries":"U.S.,Ukraine,Canada,Serbia,Spain,India",
    "cities":"Santa Clara,Ontario Quebec,Duluth,Bangalore,L.A.",
    "vendors":"EPAM,FTE,ITC,L&T TS,G&L,Phalita,Assistera",
    "overallSayDo":60,
    "commitedSayDo":49.36,
    "extraSayDo":37.57
},
{
    "teamName":"EPAM Backend 1,Cloud Engineering,Content Infrastructure Montreal,Jedi,Seal Team India - APIs,Seal Team India - Security,Seal Team X,Seal Team X India,Sith,UC Live,WeRTV,Krazy Kanucks,Seal Team India - Core,Operator Portal",
    "sprintName":"MF-S96",
    "director":"Rajesh",
    "locations":"Ukraine,SC,Duluth,India,Montreal,LA",
    "countries":"U.S.,Ukraine,Canada,Serbia,Spain,India",
    "cities":"Santa Clara,Ontario Quebec,Duluth,Bangalore,L.A.",
    "vendors":"EPAM,FTE,ITC,L&T TS,G&L,Phalita,Assistera",
    "overallSayDo":15.14,
    "commitedSayDo":15,
    "extraSayDo":0.93
},
{
    "teamName":"EPAM Backend 1,Cloud Engineering,Content Infrastructure Montreal,Jedi,Seal Team India - APIs,Seal Team India - Security,Seal Team X,Seal Team X India,Sith,UC Live,WeRTV,Krazy Kanucks,Seal Team India - Core,Operator Portal",
    "sprintName":"MF-S95",
    "director":"Rajesh",
    "locations":"Ukraine,SC,Duluth,India,Montreal,LA",
    "countries":"U.S.,Ukraine,Canada,Serbia,Spain,India",
    "cities":"Santa Clara,Ontario Quebec,Duluth,Bangalore,L.A.",
    "vendors":"EPAM,FTE,ITC,L&T TS,G&L,Phalita,Assistera",
    "overallSayDo":66.64,
    "commitedSayDo":62,
    "extraSayDo":19.79
},
{
    "teamName":"EPAM Backend 1,Cloud Engineering,Content Infrastructure Montreal,Jedi,Seal Team India - APIs,Seal Team India - Security,Seal Team X,Seal Team X India,Sith,UC Live,WeRTV,Krazy Kanucks,Seal Team India - Core,Operator Portal",
    "sprintName":"MF-S94",
    "director":"Rajesh",
    "locations":"Ukraine,SC,Duluth,India,Montreal,LA",
    "countries":"U.S.,Ukraine,Canada,Serbia,Spain,India",
    "cities":"Santa Clara,Ontario Quebec,Duluth,Bangalore,L.A.",
    "vendors":"EPAM,FTE,ITC,L&T TS,G&L,Phalita,Assistera",
    "overallSayDo":55.57,
    "commitedSayDo":50.36,
    "extraSayDo":35.29
}
]
```

How can i fix the append statement?

Comment: The error is pretty clear. Why are you giving two arguments to `append`?

Comment: We don't need the sample`JSON` data, we dont need it. 
Please remove it. Its just clutter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is clear like we see from the error.
Just change it to:

```
category_director_dataset.append("DIRECTOR+SPRINTNAME")
category_director_dataset.append({'overallSayDo': 'overallSayDo_value', 
'commitedSayDo': 'commitedSayDo_value', 'extraSayDo': 'extraSayDo_value'})
```

Comment: I want to append these calculated values based on Director and Sprintname. Hence i'm using Director and Sprintname as the key. With this, it is printing Director and Sprintname too

Comment: Not sure I completely understand what you mean but if i do then why not to try this: 
    category_director_dataset.append({'director_name+sprint_name': {'overallSayDo': 'overallSayDo_value', 'commitedSayDo': 'commitedSayDo_value', 'extraSayDo': 'extraSayDo_value'}})

This way you have a key as the director and sprint names (concatenated) and a value as a dict also which contains all the data you want.

Answer (score 0):

**The error**

The error can be found is in this line:

```
category_director_dataset.append("DIRECTOR+SPRINTNAME", {'overallSayDo': 'overallSayDo_value', 'commitedSayDo': 'commitedSayDo_value', 'extraSayDo': 'extraSayDo_value'})
                                                      ^
                                                      ^ error is this comma here
```

Which can basically be reduced to:

```
a_list.append(value1, value2)
```

Read your error message carefully:

> TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

The [`append(x)`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) method only takes one argument but you've put two arguments in it.

**What you can do**

1. Put your arguments into one tuple (surround them with parentheses) to reduce the number of arguments to one
2. Use another data structure (maybe a dictionary would be useful for your case because you already mentioned you want to use `DIRECTOR+SPRINTNAME` as a key?)

**With a dictionary**

```
DIRECTOR = "director"
SPRINTNAME = "sprint"
category_director_dataset = {}
category_director_dataset[DIRECTOR + SPRINTNAME] = { ... your data here ... }
```

So if you want to retrieve the JSON for a given `DIRECTOR + SPRINTNAME` you can simply do:

```
json = category_director_dataset[DIRECTOR + SPRINTNAME]
```